# Automatic log out for whole application

Tags: java, android

I have an application which has many activities that logins towards a web service. However my client want this application to log out after a certain timing of inactivity. Which includes screen off or no user interaction. I used the timer before but it will only work on a single activity and if i were to set the timer for 2 activities, 2 timers will be started and i'm not able to reset the previous timer when it moves on to the next activity.

I've thought that if i create a java class and extends Activity and all activities shares the same timer. Which means each time I need to start a timer, I will call the method on the java class.

Please advise or give suggestions on what actually should be done

Comment: You could create a "TimerSingleton" that you access from each activity and that you reset for each user activity.

Comment: Another posibility is to create your timer inside the application class, and you'll have only one for all activities.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Will look into that.